# Encoding an object instead of each property

Tags: javascript, xss

Very late to the game -

I've just now started to think about XSS on my website. Unfortunately, in several places I created objects that I pass via Ajax:

```
var params = {};
params.firstName = $("#firstName").val();
params.lastName = $("#lastName").val();

$.ajax({url:url, data:params}).done();
```

Anyone can write in executable JS. Now, from what I've read, I can easily remedy this situation by doing this:

```
var params = {};
params.firstName = encodeURIComponent($("#firstName").val());
params.lastName = encodeURIComponent($("#lastName").val());

$.ajax({url:url}, data:params).done();
```

But instead of going through every place I create an object and wrapping every field in encodeURIComponent --- is there any way to simply escape characters directly on the params instead of on each property?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Update: When Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 then form data is automatically encoded.

Comment: i think jquery actually does this for you

Comment: For security though, escape all these characters on the server-side, not the client. Escaping it on the client makes XSS harder, but it still is totally possible and not that hard.

Comment: @nicovank - yes, very good point. all endpoints will be secured as well. I was just doing this as an added measure because i thought the UI should take some steps against XSS.

Comment: @aw04 - My bad, you are correct. When the content type is set to :application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 then jQuery will automatically encode all form data. I'll update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would work:

```
function encodeParams(data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        data[key] = encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
    });

    return data;
}
```

You could use like so:

```
var params = encodeParams({
    firstName: $('firstName').val(),
    lastName: $('lastName').val()
});

ajax(...)
```